# Flask is always returning Redirect page

Tags: python, flask

I just installed [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I attempted to quickly test it with [their example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), but it's not working.

I have this so far:

Hello.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

then I run:

```
@ubuntu:~/repo/test/flask$ python hello.py 
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

and when I connect to localhost:5000/  and even any variation of the url, it returns

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

I'm 99% sure I have everything installed, python 2.6.5

Comment: Maybe try running it on a different port?  Some other application could be using 5000 and mucking things up?

Comment: Could you check HTTP headers of your redirect? Are they coming from Flask? Are you using proxy? Do you have IPv6 on your machine? Could you try to request `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` instead, not using "localhost" name?

Comment: Change your `app.run()` to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` and see if the logs show you more detail ?

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1:5000 as well but same thing. Ill mess around with my internet configurations. Yes to proxy (Idk why that would matter, it local isn't it?)

Comment: Adding app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True) doesnt help same response, different port returns the same thing too.

Comment: try running `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and look for the location header, what does it say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to your proxy.
Try checking `$http_proxy`, and if this value is set, try executing `unset http_proxy` before running the dev server:

Somebody had the same issue running rails:
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=36621