# web app application service deployed on docker container yields redirected POST curls

Tags: docker, rest, http, networking, service

I am a bit new to full-stack web development & networking.

I have built an full-stack application with a PostgreSQL DB interfacing with a restful C++ Backend that is acting as a application server, and a React frontend that interfaces with the backend through POST requests/responses.

Essentially, I've done all my development on some host machine, where it works perfectly, and I am trying to containerize my entire application into one docker container for deployment (I am aware that it could be argued to separate my application into 3 docker containers, one for backend, frontend, and DB, but I want it in ONE docker container). I have been adding to this docker image: https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi7/ubi/5c3592dcd70cc534b3a37814?container-tabs=overview

The issue I am running into is that the frontend is not interfacing with the backend within the container. On my host machine, generally I can test if the backend service is working when I perform a curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @Input.json http://localhost:8080/resource
```

Some data, which is the response json, will be printed to stdout on success 100% of the time when running on the host

I've only ever tested my application on the host just via localhost for development, and the C++ backend service I only set options for the port to be at 8080. I am using the restbed library: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed

The backend does not register receiving any requests.

The issue is that performing the curl within the container yields the following:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the solution -

[Flask is always returning Redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315114/flask-is-always-returning-redirect-page)

Simply just needed to remove my proxy